# Setting a state using spread operator updates the state vs setting the same object not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have an initial object called as `initUser`, it consists of initial fields of the user as follows

```
const initUser: UserProfile = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    // and so on
};
```

The object is very big, it has more than 30 fields in it. So while re initialising the state to its initial state, I did this

```
setUser(initUser);
```

Which didn't work.

But when I did this

```
setUser({...initUser});
```

It started to work, although the spread operator is very expensive as it makes the copy of the variable, so any idea why passing the variable is not working? Thank you in advance.

PS: The `initUser` is placed in another file and is imported correctly since its working properly in the spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

React will only update when the reference of the object on state is updated. Since `Object.is(initUser, initUser); // true` React will skip updating because it thinks nothing has changed.

Using the spread operator creates a new object, and thus creates a new reference.

The spread operator is very cheap because it creates a shallow copy, all the objects inside initUser will keep their references.

Answer (score 0):

30 fields in object is.. not really big :)
firstly, you can init the state like this [state, setState] = useState(initObject)

Then when you need to update the state without mutating is, you can follow the guide here: Updating Objects in State - https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state

Finally, when you write setUser({...initUser}); -> it actually clone to a new object and that's why you see the change :)